# Mat::ones() performance

Tags: c++, opencv

I am developing a software operating in real time in C++ with opencv and need the highest performance possible.
Which is more efficient?

```
Mat matrix = Mat::ones(m, n, CV_32SC1);
```

or this option

```
int** matrix = new int*[m];
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = new int[n];
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = 1;
}
```

and indexing

```
matrix.at<int>(r,c) = 10;
```

vs

```
matrix[r][c] = 10;
```

Comment: a 4x5 matrix of ints allocation will hardly matter for performance

Comment: @dwcanillas: But locality of reference will likely matter. I have no idea about the performance of `Mat`, but the second version is clearly not optimal.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth

Comment: Measure it. But how is a newed array of newed arrays comparable to a `cv::Mat`?

Comment: How do you know this is your bottleneck?   How have you attempted to measure this operations and what failed about those attempts?   What are  your estimates on the sizes of the matrices?   Min/Max/Mode/etc?   What other representations of the data have you considered?

Comment: At least transform your second loop in a `memset(matrix[i],1,n)`. Ideally you should have one array of `int` (not an array of arrays of `int`). Then you would have `memset(matrix,1,m*n)`. Which I believe is the fastest existing (as long as you have a good compiler).

Comment: I don't understand the question... if you want to use OpenCV functions later, you probably want to use cv::Mat objects right in the beginning. If you just want some 2D array, you shouldnt add openCV libraries to your project just for that (OpenCV Matrices do have some overhead, too).